# Is it possible to create route for both HTTP and HTTPS with the same host for a service?

Tags: openshift

I have created a route for HTTP, and when creating another route with the same host, the status of the route will be "Rejected".

**Is it possible to create route for both HTTP and HTTPS with the same host for a service?**

I am using the openshift sandbox:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, it is because the host is already been used by the HTTP route. What I need to do is to update existing route with the TLS settings, and set the "Insecure traffic" to "Allow"

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Route
spec:
  tls:
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Allow
```